# Email validation for exotic characters

Tags: validation, email, grails, grails-validation

It seems that the email validation in Grails just apply a [simple regex](http://blog.terrencemiao.com/technology/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression-in-groovy/). While it validates most emails, some exotic but authorized characters will make the validation fail.

The German ß character for example is used [in some email addresses](https://hilfe-center.1und1.de/hosting/e-mail-und-office-c10082645/1und1-mail-basic-c10082704/einrichtung-c10082754/besonderheiten-bei-e-mail-adressen-mit-eszett-ss-a10783810.html), but won't pass the grail validation:

```
package com.stuff.user.AppUser

import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * Created by hschoonjans on 21/03/2016.
 */
@Mock(AppUser)
class AppUserSpec extends Specification {

    def "It doesn't validate an email with an eszett"() {
        given:
        AppUser user = new AppUser(email: "helainß@hotmail.com")

        expect:
        !user.validate(["email"])
    }
}
```

Using a custom regex for validation, authorizing the ß would be trivial but what if a user tries to use another exotic yet valid character in his mail address?

To avoid this problem, I would like to know what Java/Groovy/Grails universal email address validator exist. A class/regex that would validate any valid email address, smarter than the current Grails email validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this several times before in my own Grails projects and I've had pretty good success using this RegEx:

```
/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i
```

Comment: Hey @Joshua! Can you give more information about what's your regex does or the source of this regular expression? I would like to be sure it can't match invalid urls and know more about the ranges of email addresses it accepts...

Comment: Well it's a best effort to validate to the RFC822 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt?number=822) it's grown organically over the last 18 years at the company I work for. It attempts to handle extended ASCII characters for international clients and we haven't had a complaint of a valid e-mail address being rejected by this in years. I would recommend you test it using some sample data and verify the results match your expectations. Pulling the entire thing a part and explaining it would almost require a mini-book ;)

Comment: Thanks, a lot, I'll try to find asap a generator to get strings from regexes, it will give me an idea of the kind of emails it can handle :)